# Tkinter GUI and Signal.py - ValueError: signal only works in main thread

Tags: python, tkinter, signals, mqtt

Good Day Everyone

I'm currently trying to integrate IoT communication to [KAAIoT](https://www.kaaproject.org/) using MQTT in python that sends data read from a motor driver's holding register. The Script runs on a Raspberry pi with a Tkinter GUI to do some controls, but now I want to monitor and control some things via an IoT interface.

I tested an example script provided [here](https://docs.kaaiot.io/KAA/docs/v1.2.0/Tutorials/getting-started/sending-commands-to-device/) and managed to send and receive some junk data, Cool beans, but the problems comes when trying to integrate it into the application.

Attempt 1: Implemented to code into the main class.
Result: The connection is made, but the GUI doesn't load due to the loop in the main

Code Example [Here](https://github.com/YuMChUM/KaaIoT-Connection-Tkinter-GUI-.git)

Attempt 2: Run the "main" code in a thread.
Result: Error

> **File "/usr/lib/python3.7/signal.py", line 47, in signal
> handler = _signal.signal(_enum_to_int(signalnum), _enum_to_int(handler))
> ValueError: signal only works in main thread <--------**

So if I understand this right, the signal module needs the main thread that Tkinter is using for the display GUI, but if its using it, it inhibits the GUI. The use of the main thread is also explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) under Signals and Threads.

**The Question:** Is it possible to integrate both the GUI and MQTT in some way? Any fixes or working alternatives would be appreciated.

Comment: Better provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I Usually add one but skipped it due to the exstra KAAIoT setup required. I added a basic (but still lengthy) link to the script under Attempt 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the MQTT stuff in a separate function and use thread to execute this function:

```py
import threading
...

class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        clock()
        
        self.listener = SignalListener()
        threading.Thread(target=self.client_task, daemon=True).start()

    def client_task(self):        
        client = mqtt.Client(client_id=''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(6)))

        data_collection_client = DataCollectionClient(client)
        data_collection_client.connect_to_server()

        client.on_message = on_message

        # Start the loop
        client.loop_start()

        fuelLevel, minTemp, maxTemp = 100, 95, 100

        # Send data samples in loop
        while self.listener.keepRunning:
            payload = data_collection_client.compose_data_sample(fuelLevel, minTemp, maxTemp)
            result = data_collection_client.client.publish(topic=data_collection_client.data_collection_topic, payload=payload)
            if result.rc != 0:
                print('Server connection lost, attempting to reconnect')
                data_collection_client.connect_to_server()
            else:
                print(f'--> Sent message on topic "{data_collection_client.data_collection_topic}":\n{payload}')

            time.sleep(3)

            fuelLevel = fuelLevel - 0.3
            if fuelLevel < 1:
                fuelLevel = 100

        data_collection_client.disconnect_from_server()
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that was even an option. When I ran it via another class with a thread it resulted in the error but somehow running it threaded here works.

You saved me a lot of trouble, thank you very much! i'd upvote 2x if I could